# GTM nonce-aware script does not work on all browsers for Custom HTML tags

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy, vue-ssr

I have a Vue application that uses SSR. In order to implement Content-Security-Policy, I use [nonce-aware version of GTM snippet](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp).

But it was not adding the `nonce` to all scripts that get injected by gtm to the page (specifically Custom HTML tags). I followed the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) and it fixed the issue on Safari. But it doesn't work on **Chrome**, **Firefox**, or **Edge** and I still see the error for those tags:

[image]

this is my CSP settings:

```
default-src 'self';
base-uri 'self';
block-all-mixed-content;
font-src 'self' https: https://fonts.gstatic.com data:;
img-src 'self' https: data: https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.gstatic.com  https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googletagmanager.com;
object-src 'none';
script-src 'self' 'nonce-b62382357618aee340fc9dc596c94a19' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://tagmanager.google.com https://www.googletagmanager.com 127.0.0.1:*;
script-src-attr 'none';
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://tagmanager.google.com https://fonts.googleapis.com;
upgrade-insecure-requests;
connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;
```

After hours and hours of research I found the following comment:

> Chrome masks the nonce attribute value so tag manager is unable to grab it and store it as a variable.

I am not sure if this is really the issue but can anyone please explain how I can tackle this issue without using `unsafe-inline` or hashes as it seems there is no standard way of fixing it even on Google documentations?

Comment: Pls have a look to [GTM: how to propagate `'nonce'` to Custom HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) and do not forget to tick [`Support document.write` checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66562350/google-tag-manager-any-possible-way-of-adding-csp-nonce-to-custom-html-snippet/66573603#66573603).

Comment: @granty Thanks for the reply. I have seen this question before creating this one. I followed the steps provided there and ticked the Support document.write checkbox and I confirm that I see the `nonce` attr in each custom HTML item. But the thing is that it only works on Safari but not on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. I'm using Mac Catalina 10.15.1 and all the browsers are the latest version. Any other idea that may fix this issue?

Comment: I can see the log that I put in my script tag on GTM only on Safari. Not on the others. I cleared my browser cache, tested it on Incognito mode, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot on the internet and reading different articles, I found out the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) works perfectly well in Safari but not in other browsers because:

> Chrome, Safari, and Edge mask the nonce attribute value so GTM is unable to grab it and store it as a variable.

Considering [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) for propagating the `nonce` to the custom HTML tags, we go ahead and apply the following changes to fix this issue on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.
As suggested [here in the comments](https://dev.to/matijamrkaic/using-google-tag-manager-with-a-content-security-policy-9ai) we need to modify the nonce-aware script a little bit and put the nonce in a `data-` attribute (then the browsers won't mask it), and push it to the dataLayer:

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script
  nonce='{{YOUR_GTM_NONCE}}'
  data-gtm-nonce='{{YOUR_GTM_NONCE}}'
>
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){
    const gtmNonce = d.querySelector('[data-gtm-nonce]').dataset.gtmNonce;
    w[l]=w[l]||[];
    w[l].push({'nonce': gtmNonce});
    w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
    const f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
    j.setAttribute('nonce', gtmNonce);
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','YOUR_GTM_ID');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Then in the GTM, you need to change the nonce variable you defined based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100704/gtm-not-propagating-nonce-to-custom-html-tags) ***from this***:
[image]

***to this***:
[image]

The rest will be kept the same.

Comment: After some thinking I would make 2 changes:
1. remove attribute "data-gtm-nonce" - it's not safe. You can use CSS atack if you will show nonce value.
2. get nonce value similar to GTM script:
    var n = d.querySelector('[nonce]');
    var h = n.nonce || n.getAttribute('nonce');
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({ nonce: h });
... (other code).
I had also submitted for GTM Variable Configuration fix: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/125251086/storing-nonce-variable-from-dom-element?hl=en